# Simple :hover never gets triggered

Tags: css

I have some :hover CSS:

```
.btnSimple {
    /*some css*/
}

<a href="" class="btnSimple">hover</a>
```

But those rule never get applied. Link:

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UnFhQ/78/

Comment: which browser you trying?

Comment: triggering perfectly in chrome 25

Comment: but its working here too..!

Comment: Which browser ? Have you noticed that you are using `#FFF` for border-color ?

Comment: Ok for me...(firefox) background blue. It turns white on hover

Comment: Sorry wrong link, please retry. I have updated the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UnFhQ/73/

Comment: Please . tell us what kind of hover effect are you looking for.

Comment: Just remove display property from your class

Comment: Sachin's suggestion fixes it. Confirmed in Chrome 25.

Comment: I confirm it too. @Sachin

Comment: Third confirm.  Sachin saves the day.

Comment: Is there any resons behind this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't declared the transition on the `.btnSmall` class itself. You must first specify the `transition-property` and the `transition-duration` properties on the class, and then apply those properties you wish to transition on `btnSmall:hover`

If you want to apply more than one property for the `transition` property you can include the `all` keyword so that multiple properties can be transitioned.

Simple example:

```
.btnClass {
 transition: all 2s;
}

.btnClass:hover {
background: #fff;
border: 2px solid cornflowerblue;
}
```